# Printing to Thermal Printer (Using Forms 6i)

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I am using oracle forms 6i and want to print my POS invoice on thermal printer. I already have "continuous" printing directly on dot matrix printer where I am opening my LPT port through `text_io` package and generating invoice as per the requirement.

Now, the customer wants to generate the invoice on a thermal printer. Suppose, I want to print 9 lines on printer page then after 9 lines printing must be stop.

My code is as follows :

```
declare 
 pvf_file text_io.file_type; 
 vs_prn_port varchar2(128) :='LPT1'; 
begin 
 lpt1:= Text_IO.Fopen(vs_prn_port,'a'); 
 text_io.put_line('This is a first line.' ); 
 text_io.fclose(lpt1); 
end;
```

Please guide me if you have any thoughts.

Comment: There won't be any Oracle Forms built-ins which will understand the concept of "thermal printer". So you'll need to write some bespoke code, which presumably means changing what you already have. You may also need to write some external code (such as a VBX component) to interface with the thermal printer,  This is not something we can help with, given that we can't see your code, your application or your operating environment.

Comment: for dot matrix printer: I used text_io package to open my LPT port and sending text accordingly. My syntax is as follow:

declare
  pvf_file text_io.file_type;
  vs_prn_port varchar2(128) :='LPT1';
begin
  lpt1:= Text_IO.Fopen(vs_prn_port,'a'); 
  text_io.put_line('This is a first line.' );
  text_io.fclose(lpt1);
end;

I want to get idea how can i continuous print on my USB port??

Comment: If you're going to post some code - or indeed improve your question in any way - please **edit the question body**. Comments are for comments, and code is especially hard to read without decent layout.

Comment: is there any luck.